# NSDate format for all the region formats

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, nsdate

Is there any date format for NSDateFormatter that is applicable to all the region formats. That can be work on:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"?"];
NSDate *testDate = [dateformat dateFromString:@"%@ %@",dateStr,timeStr];
NSLog(@"%@",testDate);
```

Anybody know about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special formatting attributes `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`. They work for all regional formats, but you will have to find out yourself which one is suitable for your particular case. The input for these s the same for date and time. For example:

```
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
```

Here is what is available:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSDateFormatterStyle) {    // date and time format styles
    NSDateFormatterNoStyle = kCFDateFormatterNoStyle,
    NSDateFormatterShortStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle,
    NSDateFormatterMediumStyle = kCFDateFormatterMediumStyle,
    NSDateFormatterLongStyle = kCFDateFormatterLongStyle,
    NSDateFormatterFullStyle = kCFDateFormatterFullStyle
};
```